# "refused to set unsafe header cookie" in Axios Request

Tags: axios

i'm trying to send cookie:

```
    axios.get('https://localhost:44303/api/Home',{headers:{
      
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("user"),
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                  'Cookie': document.cookie
                 // передача токена в заголовке
            },credentials: "same-origin"}, ).
            then(Response =>this.games=Response.data );
          
      },
```

and i'm getting this error:
[image]

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: A little googling took me to this [link in github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/319). Hope this helps.